# JS table sorting fail on Chrome

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-chrome, html-table, client-side

I am working on a website that allow people to participate in an online race on erg rowers.

I display a large table (600+ rows) containing rank, name and other fields, and I want to allow visitors to sort it on the fly (client-side JS).
**I set up a function that works really well on Firefox, but it doesn't work at all on Chrome browsers.**

I really don't see what part of my code can bring this problem, this is why I reach to you for some help !

My html code looks like:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>...</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>USER 1</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And my JavaScript:

```js
for (const table of document.getElementsByTagName('table')) {
  const headers = table.querySelectorAll('thead tr th');
  for (let i = 0; i < headers.length-1; i++) {
    headers[i].addEventListener('click', sortTable(i, table.id));
  }
}

function sortTable(n, tableId) {
  return () => {
    const table = document.getElementById(tableId);

    const newTable = document.createElement('table');
    newTable.className = table.className;
    newTable.id = table.id;

    const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    const thead = document.createElement('thead');

    const rows = Array.from(table.rows);
    thead.appendChild(rows.shift());
    const th = thead.getElementsByTagName('th');

    const dir = th[n].className == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';

    rows.sort((a, b) => {
      let x = a.getElementsByTagName('td')[n].innerText.toLowerCase();
      let y = b.getElementsByTagName('td')[n].innerText.toLowerCase();

      const compare = x.localeCompare(y, 'fr', { sensitivity: 'base', numeric: true });

      return ((dir == 'asc' && compare > 0) || (dir == 'desc' && compare < 0));
    })
      .forEach(row => tbody.appendChild(row));

    for (const header of th) {
      header.className = '';
    }

    th[n].className = dir;

    newTable.appendChild(thead);
    newTable.appendChild(tbody);

    table.parentNode.replaceChild(newTable, table);
  };
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work at all" what does that mean exactly?  You click it and nothing happens?  Or it sorts incorrectly?  Or it hangs?  Are there any error messages shown?  What's the actual behavior?

Comment: I suspect it's just very slow for such a large table. Calling `getElementsByTagName()` in every comparison is going to be expensive.

Comment: @AlexanderNied It actually "sorts" (replace the table content) by with the initial order, and then display the header's arrow indicating if ascending or descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison function passed to `.sort()` is returning a boolean:

```
return ((dir == 'asc' && compare > 0) || (dir == 'desc' && compare < 0));
```

However, the [`.sort()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) expects this comparison function to return a number.  I suspect that Firefox is being forgiving or doing some type conversion for you where Chrome is not.  If I change it to:

```
return ((dir == 'asc' && 0 + compare) || (dir == 'desc' && 0 - compare));
```

...it *will* sort as expected.

```js
for (const table of document.getElementsByTagName('table')) {
  const headers = table.querySelectorAll('thead tr th');
  for (let i = 0; i < headers.length - 1; i++) {
    headers[i].addEventListener('click', sortTable(i, table.id));
  }
}

function sortTable(n, tableId) {
  return () => {
    const table = document.getElementById(tableId);

    const newTable = document.createElement('table');
    newTable.className = table.className;
    newTable.id = table.id;

    const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    const thead = document.createElement('thead');

    const rows = Array.from(table.rows);
    thead.appendChild(rows.shift());
    const th = thead.getElementsByTagName('th');

    const dir = th[n].className == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';

    rows.sort((a, b) => {
        let x = a.getElementsByTagName('td')[n].innerText.toLowerCase();
        let y = b.getElementsByTagName('td')[n].innerText.toLowerCase();

        const compare = x.localeCompare(y, 'fr', {
          sensitivity: 'base',
          numeric: true
        });

        return ((dir == 'asc' && 0 + compare) || (dir == 'desc' &&  0 - compare));
      })
      .forEach(row => tbody.appendChild(row));

    for (const header of th) {
      header.className = '';
    }

    th[n].className = dir;

    newTable.appendChild(thead);
    newTable.appendChild(tbody);

    table.parentNode.replaceChild(newTable, table);
  };
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>USER 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>USER 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>USER 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>USER 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>USER 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>USER 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>USER 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>USER 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>USER 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>USER 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>USER 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>USER 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>USER 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>USER 14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>USER 15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>USER 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>USER 17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>USER 18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>USER 19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>USER 20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>USER 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>USER 22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>USER 23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>USER 24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>USER 25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>USER 26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>USER 27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>USER 28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>USER 29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>USER 30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

(For reference, here is the original version, where simply a boolean was returned, and the sorting does not work at all):

```js
for (const table of document.getElementsByTagName('table')) {
  const headers = table.querySelectorAll('thead tr th');
  for (let i = 0; i < headers.length - 1; i++) {
    headers[i].addEventListener('click', sortTable(i, table.id));
  }
}

function sortTable(n, tableId) {
  return () => {
    const table = document.getElementById(tableId);

    const newTable = document.createElement('table');
    newTable.className = table.className;
    newTable.id = table.id;

    const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    const thead = document.createElement('thead');

    const rows = Array.from(table.rows);
    thead.appendChild(rows.shift());
    const th = thead.getElementsByTagName('th');

    const dir = th[n].className == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';

    rows.sort((a, b) => {
        let x = a.getElementsByTagName('td')[n].innerText.toLowerCase();
        let y = b.getElementsByTagName('td')[n].innerText.toLowerCase();

        const compare = x.localeCompare(y, 'fr', {
          sensitivity: 'base',
          numeric: true
        });

        return ((dir == 'asc' && compare > 0) || (dir == 'desc' && compare < 0));
      })
      .forEach(row => tbody.appendChild(row));

    for (const header of th) {
      header.className = '';
    }

    th[n].className = dir;

    newTable.appendChild(thead);
    newTable.appendChild(tbody);

    table.parentNode.replaceChild(newTable, table);
  };
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>USER 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>USER 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>USER 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>USER 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>USER 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>USER 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>USER 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>USER 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>USER 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>USER 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>USER 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>USER 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>USER 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>USER 14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>USER 15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>USER 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>USER 17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>USER 18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>USER 19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>USER 20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>USER 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>USER 22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>USER 23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>USER 24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>USER 25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>USER 26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>USER 27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>USER 28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>USER 29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>USER 30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much !
I suspected that and added a Number cast on the whole condition but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

`a.getElementsByTagName('td')` is a pretty expensive operation, calling it during every comparison is going to be slow.

Table rows have a `cells` property that contains all the `td` and `th` elements, you can use that instead.

```
      let x = a.cells[n].innerText.toLowerCase();
      let y = b.cells[n].innerText.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip !
I now use `cells` but it doesn't seem to impact speed, either on Firefox or Chrome.
I dug a bit to see what takes most time, and it is by far Style and Layout. I don't know if there is a way to improve that.